# Getting Friend List of twitter user using TwitteR package

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I'm having some problems getting the Friend List of a twitter user from R, using the [TwitteR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/).

What I want to get is a character vector with the names of all the "Friends" of a user - this is, the list of people he/she is following.

Following the documentation, I thought this code would work:

```
    library("twitteR")
    user <- getUser("@twitter")
    user$getFriends()
```

But I get the following error message:

```
    Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) :
    "friendIDs" is not a valid field or method name for reference class "user"
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this was a bug that I just fixed tonight (a severe lack of time has struck lately).  The latest version (0.99.12) should fix this problem.

Comment: i still have this problem with version 0.99.9:> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252    LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_0.99.9 RJSONIO_0.95-0 RCurl_1.5-0.1  bitops_1.0-4.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's a bug or what, but it works if you get the Friend IDs first and then look up the Friend Names by ID:

```
> lookupUsers(user$getFriendsIDs(5))
$`11`
[1] "RaymondAtWork"

$`12`
[1] "stevegury"

$`13`
[1] "josolennoso"

$`14`
[1] "mjackson"

$`15`
[1] "billonahill"
```

BTW if you haven't done so, I think you need to set up `ROAuth` for these `lookupUsers()` calls.

Comment: Good to hear. Have fun with `twitteR`!